# How to list uid of all the users of LDAP?

Tags: bash, ldap, uid

I get list of all the users of LDAP using the following command `ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=* > result`.

The result of the following command results in following format

```
dn: uid=shahrukh,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
uid: shahrukh
cn: shahrukh
sn: shahrukh
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1086
gidNumber: 1086
homeDirectory: /home/ldap/shahrukh
```

There is a complete list of these records.

I want to shortlist all the uid in one file such that only value of uid should be listed.

```
shahrukh
abc
xyz
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 9):

You can specify attributes after your filter, and it will only display those attributes.

E.g.:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=* uid > result
```

This might give you a bunch of `uid: 12345` lines. You might then have to pipe it through `sed` to remove the bit you don't want. (Alternatively, if you do it with `perl` and `Net::LDAP` you can extract precisely what you want - but I think `ldapsearch` + `sed` is the path of least resistance).

Comment: Agreed. I would do this: ```ldapsearch -x -LLL 'uid=*' uid | sed -n 's/^uid: // p'```. That won't handle base64-encoded values (uid:: xxx), i.e. if some uid has non-printable or non-ascii characters, but I think you can fairly expect a uid to be ASCII only ;).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to pipe the results to grep and then cut. Example is

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=* | grep uid: | cut -d: -f2 > results
```

Comment: Why use `grep` when you can just ask `ldapsearch` to give you the uid you want, as in the other answer?